# Windows Server 2012 R2 long file paths not working?

Tags: windows, powershell

We have a server with Windows Server 2012 R2 installed using ReFS for the 32k MAX_PATH capabilities but it's not working as expected, especially when you compare it with Windows 10.

If you use `Test-Path` in `Powershell` on `Windows 10` with a very long UNC using the pattern below:

```
Test-Path -Path "\\?\UNC\hostname\share\very\long\path" -PathType Container
```

It will return True but if you issue the same command in `Windows Server 2012 R2` it will return False. Both systems are using the latest version of Powershell and both systems have Long Paths enabled in the registry.

Any idea as to why this is working on Windows 10 but not Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: The API to support long paths that PowerShell needs was added in Windows 10 (one of the updates.)

Comment: @travisez13 if that's all the unicode versionso of win32 file management API (i.e CreateFileW), there are Microsoft articles that say those work already with ReFS and Windows Server 2012 R2 supports ReFS shop why wouldn't it work in 2012 R2? Will direct API calls instead of powershell work in 2012 R2?

Comment: A direct call should work.  For example, you should be able to P/Invoke the call from PowerShell.  I've added an answer with a module that wraps the P/Invoke calls for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround of using [PSAlphaFS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAlphaFS/1.0.0.0) for pre-Windows 10 Anniversary Update machines.

Support for long paths was not added to PowerShell/DotNet until Windows 10.  You can see [here Long Path support was added to PowerShell in Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11685975-long-path-support)

Comment: This answers my question in a round-about way. I figured win32 API would work and already have been using that, I just wanted to know why it wasn't working and from your answer I see that .net didn't incorporate the \\?\ passthrough to unicode win32 API until .net 4.6.2 and most likely the system in question on my end is using a lower version and Powershell is using that lower version as well.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  That's a bit more detail than I have.  It all sounds correct.  I'm not confident in those details, but feel free to edit my answer and add the information.  In addition, to the correct version of .NET, I know you would also need the corresponding version of PowerShell.  I believe it is the 5.0 version of PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, this was a limitation in .NET, @vane. The NT native path escape that you propose in the question will work on any version of NT, but only if you're calling the Win32 functions directly. The NT wrapper didn't support it until .NET 4.6.2. If you need to support older versions, there is supposedly some magic that you can do to P/Invoke from PowerShell. That way, you can call the Win32 APIs directly, and then you'll be in business.

Comment: @CodyGray Interestingly my Windows 10 machine that works with long paths shows I have .net version 4.6.01586.394802 through PS and 4.6.1 in "Programs and Features" but nowhere does it show that I have 4.6.2 installed so I'm wondering if 4.6.1 or even 4.6.0 supports long paths as well.

Comment: Well, there was a *separate* change in Windows 10 Anniversary Edition that removed the MAX_PATH limitation from the standard APIs, without requiring the native NT path escape workaround. Applies only to properly-manifested apps, or using a Group Policy, so it is opt-in. Sorry, I left that out because I was trying not to make this all too confusing. @vane